# Calculate the direct voltage common mode rejection ratio for an instrument in which a common mode voltage of 100V produces an error in reading of 5mV

Tags: measurement, instrumentation

Dv/dt = 5/100 =0.05V

V * 100 =0.05 * 100= 5V

This is what I did. I can't get it right.  It's a measurement and instrumentation course, specifically an electronic engineering course.

Comment: Why do you have dv/dt? What does time have to do with it? Your units are not matching at all.

Comment: Please help me out, I just tried it out with time... what do you have about it?

Comment: @Piko:  It is a ratio.  Simply one voltage divided by another.  The trick here is the units.  Both voltages have to be in the same unit.  You have volts and millivolts.  Convert the millivolts to volts before going further.

Comment: The units cancel.  It's like with regular variables. \$\frac{20X}{4X} = 5\$ . When you divide volts by volts, the result has no unit.

Comment: I appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The amount of output voltage error (in your case 5mV) in proportion to the input common mode voltage (in your case 100V) is the common mode rejection ratio. This has nothing to do with time, so no need to specify some dV/dt.

\$ CMRR = \frac{V_{out}}{V_{com_i}} = \frac{5~mV}{100~V} = 50 \cdot 10^{-6}\$

As you can the, the CMRR (Common mode rejection ratio) has no unit, because it is a ratio.

Typically the value of the CMRR is not given as a linear number, but in the logarithmic measure of dB:

\$ CMRR_{dB} = 20 \cdot log(CMRR) = -86~dB \$

Notice that *dB* is not a unit! It only is scaling the linear value of the CMRR to a logarithmic scale.

Comment: Thanks alot, I appreciate...

Comment: Thanks alot, I appreciate...